# Expressão Regular, preg_match() e armazenamento em um array

Tags: php, regex

**Olá**. Tenho um *.txt* ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZahBpDnm)) que contém o log dos clientes conectados em um servidor ***openvpn*** e o formato de cada uma das linhas é o abaixo:

```
CLIENT_LIST orion-01889596000195    177.43.212.110:28763    172.16.191.145  872199  860412  Wed May 25 07:22:52 2016    1464171772  UNDEF
```

Estou usando a função `preg_match()` para armazenar cada resultado em uma posição de um array. Fiz o código de duas formas.

**Primeira forma**

---

```
$log = "log.txt";
$handle = fopen($log, "r");

$inclients = false;
$cdata = array();

while (!feof($handle))
{
 $line = fgets($handle, 4096);

 if (substr($line, 0, 11) == "CLIENT_LIST")
 {
  $inclients = true;
 }
 if ($inclients)
 {
  preg_match("/\w+-\d{14}/", $line, $cdata);
  preg_match("/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\:[0-9]+/", $line, $cdata[1]);
  preg_match("/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/", $line, $cdata[2]);
  preg_match("/\s+[0-9]+/", $line, $cdata[3]);
 return var_dump($cdata[0], $cdata[1], $cdata[2], $cdata[3]);
 }
}
```

**Segunda forma**

---

```
if ($inclients)
{
 preg_match("/\w+-\d{14}\s+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\. [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+/", $line, $cdata);
 var_dump($cdata);
}
```

---

Problemas que encontrei na primeira forma: o nome (**orion-01889596000195**) e o 1º ip (**177.43.212.110:28763**) consegui armazenar em `$cdata[0]` e `$cdata[1]`  porém ao armazenar o 2º ip (**172.16.191.145**) em `$cdata[3]` ele volta a pegar o 1º ip mas sem a numeração após **":"**. E os outros dados quais necessito armazenar são: **872199**, **860412** e **1464171772** não consegui chegar neles.

Problemas que encontrei na segunda forma: creio que foi armazenado em `$cdata[0]` as seguintes informações: `array(1) { [0]=> string(70) "orion-01889596000195  177.43.212.110:28763    172.16.191.145  872199  860412" }` e por isso não sei como pegar cada informação separadamente. Apesar de eu ter conseguido capturar o resultado **860412** não consegui avançar entre **Wed May 25 07:22:52 2016** até chegar em **1464171772**.

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: Acho que será melhor separar por linhas e depois aplicar regras linha a linha. Vou testar mais logo e coloco uma reposta se ninguem tiver resolvido ainda. O que me preocupa é que tens algumas linhas com IP depois do UNDEF, isso quebra o padrão...

Comment: Essas linhas com IP depois do UNDEF seria como esta?

`CLIENT_LIST UNDEF 201.14.8.164:1134  42 54 Wed May 25 15:05:07 2016 1464199507 UNDEF`

Comment: Se sim, este UNDEF no início é um próprio bug do servidor Open VPN quando gera o log... ele não consegue identificar a **chave** (por exemplo: `orion-01889596000195`) aí ele cadastra como UNDEF

Comment: Sim, exato. Ok, isso quer dizer que todos os UNDEF devem ser strings vazias por exemplo?

Comment: Sim. A minha intenção é adicionar essas informações num banco para depois exibir numa página da web.
Como exemplo as linhas 3 e 4 do log:

`CLIENT_LIST databits-13031005000123 187.17.235.203:50515 172.16.136.217 459833 409771 Wed May 25 06:09:01 2016 1464167341 UNDEF
CLIENT_LIST UNDEF 201.14.8.164:1134  42 54 Wed May 25 15:05:07 2016 1464199507 UNDEF`




 Na terceira linha iria aparecer `databits-13031005000123 etc etc etc`
 E na quarta linha `string-vazia etc etc etc`

Comment: Ok, testa isto então: https://ideone.com/T9IIJy

Comment: @Sergio funcionou perfeitamente! Alterei o seu primeiro código e também consegui fazer funcionar perfeitamente. Agradeço imensamente cara!

Comment: Otimo, vou juntar resposta então para ficar completo e ser util a outros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendo o teu pastebin vejo que os campos estão separados por *tabs*, e como referiste `UNDEF` é no fundo um valor nulo, undefined que pode ser convertido em string vazia. Então podes fazer isso assim:

```
function processador($str){
    $partes = preg_split("/\t/", trim($str));
    $data = array_slice($partes, 1); 
    return array_map("filtro", $data);
}
function filtro($str){
    return str_replace("UNDEF", "", $str);
}

$linhas = array_filter(explode("\n", $string));
$resultado = array_map("processador", $linhas);

echo var_dump($resultado);
```

#### ideone: https://ideone.com/b3LFzS